# inner product two rows in matrix C++ with Eigen

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, eigen

I want to do an inner product as below. 
MatrixXd a= [1,2,3,4]
MatrixXd b= [1,2,3,4]

a*b = [1,4,9,16]  <=> c[i] = a[i]*b[i].

How to do it with Eigen MatrixXd?

Thanks.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve].

Comment: The question is quite reasonable, the problem is clearly stated, the desired output is described. The only error is the wrong terminology "inner product". Several valid answers have been posted, which could be useful for future readers. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is an element-wise product, ("inner product" usually refers to the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)). You can write either:

```
a.cwiseProduct(b);
// or
a.array() * b.array();
```

But if you are mostly working with element-wise operations, you should declare `a` and `b` as `Array`:

```
Eigen::ArrayXd a{{1,2,3,4}}, b{{1,2,3,4}}; // {}-initialization requires C++11, and the development branch of Eigen
Eigen::ArrayXd c = a*b;
```

Godbolt-Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/BDprOz

Comment: Hi. I used the Eigen and test the time. It took more time than I using for(...) c[i]= a[i]*b[i]; can you suggest any method to improve that? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try compiling with optimization? (`-O2` or `-O3` with gcc/clang)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

One can use the [`.asDiagonal()`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a14235b62c90f93fe910070b4743782d0) member function for this:

```
c = a.asDiagonal() * b;
```

In this case `c` is a vector that results from the matrix-vector product of a diagonal matrix containing the elements of the vector `a` with the vector `b`. The term "vector" is used interchangeably to describe a one-dimensional matrix.

https://godbolt.org/z/9DsLj8

Here it is assumed that `b` is a column vector `MatrixXd b(4,1)`. If it is a row vector `MatrixXd b(1,4)` one can use `a.asDiagonal() * b.transpose()` instead.

I don't expect any significant difference in terms of performance between this option and the solutions suggested by @chtz.

Comment: If you write `c.noalias()` instead of `c` and enable optimizations, this should produce the same code as the array variants: https://godbolt.org/z/tkvKXU

Comment: @chtz This is very interesting. Thank you for this remark. If I understand correctly,  `.noalias()` is faster as it prevents an evaluation into a temporary before assigning the value to `c`, and the reason why this is not the default are situations like `a = a.asDiagonal() * b`. But I assume that aliasing does not play a role if the variable is declared like `VectorXd c = a.asDiagonal() * b;`, right ?

Comment: My bad. For `a.asDiagonal()*b` the `.noalias()` is indeed not necessary: https://godbolt.org/z/SWjJh7.